# How to group values together if they share the same id value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to group together authors who have worked on the same title. Currently i have the following query

```
SELECT o.Output_Author_Name, a.Output_Title_Name 
FROM output_author_country o INNER JOIN
     outputlist a
     ON o.Output_ID_fk = a.Output_ID
LIMIT 10
```

returns

[image: return table of the query]

Is there an easy way to group the authors together? So it returns

```
Floarian Mai, Iacopo Vaglina, Lukas Galke, Using Adversarial...
```

Row packet data return

```
  RowDataPacket {
    Organisation_Name: 'APHA, PH1 1RX',
    Output_Title_Name:
     'Comparison of Alternative Meat Inspection Regimes for Pigs From Non-Controlled Housing – Considering the Cost of Error',
    'GROUP_CONCAT(o.Output_Author_Name)':
```

Comment: use listagg()....

Comment: Sorry, I'm using mysql

Comment: group_concat is mysql equivalent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT Output_Title_Name,GROUP_CONCAT(Output_Author_Name)
FROM output_author_country
GROUP BY Output_Title_Name
```

Comment: How can i access the value in row packet data, updated my OP

Comment: Glad it helped! Regarding your second question, since each question might be searched by other users in future, it will be much helpful if you keep the original quedtion untouched and create a new post for the second question.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(output_author_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
output_title_name),output_title_name 
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: LISTAGG in mysql 
??

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin i already mentioned in comments group_concat is mysql's equivalent to listagg(); :-)

Comment: does this question for oracle ?

Comment: This should have been downvoted, even when you said in the comments `GROUP_CONCAT` is MySQL's equivalent  for the SQL standard `LISTAGG` function, MySQL does not simply support `LISTAGG` so this answer is just plain wrong and will give a syntax error in MySQL..