# SQL- How Can I count and list the items with same values?

Tags: sql, group-by, count, mariadb

I have this table(table name CH);

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID_A ║ ID_B ║Category_A║Category_B║
╠══════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║   1  ║   a  ║    1     ║     1    ║
║   1  ║   b  ║    1     ║     2    ║
║   1  ║   c  ║    1     ║     3    ║
║   1  ║   a  ║    2     ║     1    ║
║   1  ║   b  ║    2     ║     1    ║
║   1  ║   c  ║    2     ║     1    ║
║   1  ║   a  ║    2     ║     2    ║
║   1  ║   b  ║    2     ║     2    ║
║   1  ║   b  ║    3     ║     1    ║
║   1  ║   c  ║    3     ║     1    ║
║   2  ║   a  ║    1     ║     1    ║
║   2  ║   b  ║    1     ║     1    ║
║   2  ║   a  ║    2     ║     1    ║
║   2  ║   c  ║    2     ║     1    ║
║   2  ║   b  ║    3     ║     1    ║
║   2  ║   c  ║    3     ║     1    ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

ID(ID_A, ID_B), CAT(CAT_A,CAT_B)

ID(1,a) and ID(1,b) have same categories, CAT(2,1) and CAT(2,2).

So cnt_CAT = 2 for ID(1,a) and ID(1,b)

What table I want to get is:

```
╔══════╦══════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID_A ║ Pair ║ cnt_CAT ║   lst_CAT   ║
╠══════╬══════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
║   1  ║  a,b ║    2    ║{(2,1),(2,2)}║
║   1  ║  a,c ║    1    ║   {(2,1)}   ║
║   1  ║  b,c ║    2    ║{(2,1),(3,1)}║
║   2  ║  a,b ║    1    ║   {(1,1)}   ║
║   2  ║  a,c ║    1    ║   {(2,1)}   ║
║   2  ║  b,c ║    1    ║   {(3,1)}   ║
╚══════╩══════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
```

It seems completed. If it's too difficult to have with SQL,
then I can ignore *lst_cat* column.

Is there any way to get Pair and cnt_CAT values with SQL??

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  I also don't understand the logic for your calculation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added new tag, "mariadb". In the first table, When ID_A=1, 'a' and 'b' have same value twice, so that is cnt_CAT=2. Also these values are (CAT_A=2, CAT_B=1) and (CAT_A=2, CAT_B=2). So result table has these information.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I found this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54960325/how-to-group-values-together-if-they-share-the-same-id-value-in-sql) I think I need to try, work with this solution.

Comment: I see that "a" and "b" have the same value three times.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think I made problem confusing. 'a' and 'b' appears with these pairs (ID_A, CAT_A, CAT_B) = {(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(2,1,1)}. but I want to distinguish when ID_A=1 and ID_A=2.

Comment: "Is there any way to get Pair and cnt_CAT values with SQL??" How would you get the pairs in a programming language other then SQL, because i don't see how the pairs are related in the resultset. unless you want every pair combination which is possible within a ID_A "group" which is clearly not the case here.. So why these pairs?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Actually CAT_A and CAT_B are location information. I want to find the pairs that appears same place multiple times(>1). So 'Pair' column shows that which pair appears at the same place and 'lst_CAT' means set of places that the pair appears.

Comment: Do it in 2 steps.  Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to do one task, then put that `SELECT` as a 'derived' table for doing the second `GROUP_CONCAT`.